# Techniques for probabilistic clustering of similar looking text data?

Tags: cluster-analysis, text-processing

I have 20,000 company addresses on various documents, which are all formatted differently. For example:

- Company A
  12345 street
  US
- CompanyA, Inc
  box2, 12345 street
  WA, US
- The Company B company Ltd
  123 happy street UK
- company B, Ltd
  123, happy street, london, S1 1AA

I'd like to be able to combine the records for each company (i.e. seperate the above into 2 categories, one per company).

I have no idea about how to go about this. I assume any clustering will be probabilistic in nature, and probably work well for easier matches, but then require manual review for less likely/more uncertain matches.

Can anyone name any techniques suitable for this type of task?

many thanks!

Comment: If you know they are for certain addresses, can't you look for certain keywords and make an assumption of which cluster they belong to? The cluster that way though will be about the country of the addresses, thereby creating only two clusters. Of course if you wanted much more finely grained clusters this approach might not work.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [automatic grammar induction](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=automatic+grammar+induction&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) is a technique that would yield results here.  You could attempt to infer grammars for your text and then use some kind of comparison metrics to cluster the inferred grammars.